# How to interpret a range from 0 to 600 to a range between 1 to 0

Tags: algebra-precalculus, interpolation

Sorry for the poor wording, I'm not sure how to describe this.

As the value $x$ increases from $0$ to $600$, how can I make the value $y$ to range from $1$ to $0$. So for example, when $x = 0$, $y = 1$, and when $x=600$, $y = 0$ (and if $x=300$ then $y = 0.5$, and so on.) Any pointers in the right direction would be helpful.

Comment: If the relationship between $x,y$ is linear, you want to find the equation of the straight line that passes through $(0,1)$ and $(600,0)$, which is $y = 1- (x/600)$ in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Find the equation of the line through the points (0,1) and (600,0).

In this case, if a line has $x$-intercept $a$ and $y$-intercept $b$, then the equation of the line is

$$\frac xa + \frac yb = 1$$

In your case this would be

$$\frac{x}{600} + \frac y1 = 1$$

$$x + 600y = 600$$

$$y = 1 - \frac{1}{600}x $$

Comment: thanks so much! solved my issue

Answer (score 0):

There might be many ways to achieve this, here's one:

Define $y = 1 - \frac{x}{600}$

Comment: thanks, I knew it had to be something simple this is great

Comment: @ron_kuby This depends on the fact that the relationship between $x$ and $y$ is linear. You could also have exponential, logistic, etc.